# Test failing due to Click Intercepted only in one PC

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

The test I'm referring to is ok on my PC, but when my coworker tries to run it she receive the following message:

```
Test method EVO4.Apresentacao.Angular.Teste.Brasil.Modulos.Geral.Menus.AdministrativoContratos threw exception:
    OpenQA.Selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <a href="#tabs-log" id="btnLog" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1">...</a> is not clickable at point (342, 113). Other element would receive the click: <div style="position: relative;" class="row-fluid">...</div>
      (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.104)
```

The line of code is:

```
Driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnLog")).Click();
```

And the HTML for that button is:

```
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tabs-log" aria-labelledby="btnLog" aria-selected="false"><a href="#tabs-log" id="btnLog" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1">Histórico</a>
      <a href="#tabs-log" id="btnLog" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1">Histórico</a>
</li>
```

Element is visible on her screen by the time it's supposed to be clicked but it's in a different position than my screen, since selenium is searching by Id that doesn't make any sense to me.

Why is that not happening to me and how can I solve this to her?